# Error while running thesis code in Latex

Tags: errors, pdftex, thesis

I am writing a thesis using Winedt Editor. I got following error while running the tex file.

[image]

What does it mean? I am unable to get it. Plus, I have 8 main chapters. So do I add one more chapter in the following tex line :

```
\graphicspath{{HeadTail/},{Chapter1/},{Chapter2/},{Chapter3/},{Chapter4/},{Chapter5/},{Chapter6/},{Chapter7/}}.
```

**One more doubt.**

For all the chapters, I added pdf file for figures but while running the code to add a figure in eighth chapter it is showing .pdf or .jpg file not found, although I have saved the file in the same folder location.

Kindly help. Thanks a lot for the kind help.

I am attaching full tex code (main code) for thesis

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,openright]{book}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[a4paper, tmargin=3.5cm, bmargin=2.5cm, lmargin=3.75cm, rmargin=2.5cm, twoside]{geometry}
\usepackage{latexsym,amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}                   % AMS Math
\usepackage{rotating}                    % Sideways of figures & tables
\usepackage{natbib}                      % Cross-reference package (Natural BiB)
\usepackage{amsthm}                                          % Put References at the end of each chapter
\usepackage{enumerate}                                         % Do not put 'sectionbib' option here.
                                     % Sectionbib option in 'natbib' will do.
\usepackage{fancyhdr}                    % Fancy Header and Footer
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{losymbol}
%\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{times}
%\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\doublespace                             % Line spacing
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{appendix}
\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{Chapter}
\renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnum}{:}
\renewcommand{\cftsecpresnum}{\hspace*{1.8cm}}
\renewcommand{\cftchapnumwidth}{6.2em}
\renewcommand{\cftsecnumwidth}{7em}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecpresnum}{\hspace*{1.8cm}}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecnumwidth}{7.5em}
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}}
\graphicspath{{HeadTail/},{Chapter1/},{Chapter2/},{Chapter3/},{Chapter4/}, 
{Chapter5/},{Chapter6/},{Chapter7/}}
```

Comment: The error means you have `\begin{spacing}` without a matching `\end{spacing}`.

Comment: What does line 204 indicate? How to know it is from which chapter?

Comment: Go through your input files one by one.

Comment: unrelated to the error you show but graphics path should not have commas in it, you are specifying amsthm twice, you don't neet to specify amsmath as you have mathtools, it is better to use `newtxtext,newtxmath`  rather than the ancient `times` package